# manifest attribute of Summer13 not working on my prerelease org?

Tags: visualforce, html5, summer-13

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"
docType="html-5.0" manifest="/apex/CacheManifest">
<header>
 <h1>Congratulations!</h1>
 </header>
 <article>
 <p>This page looks almost like HTML5!</p>
 </article>
 <img src="/img/seasonLogos/2013_summer_aloha.png" />
 </apex:page>
```

I created a page in the summer 13 pre-release org .Also i tried creating the CacheManifest file through vf

```
<apex:page contentType="text/cache-manifest" applyHtmlTag="false"
 standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
CACHE MANIFEST
img/seasonLogos/2013_summer_aloha.png
</apex:page>
```

Here is the manifest file created through visualforce

I run into following error

Any idea on why this is happening?Am i missing something?

[image]

Comment: I've not done any HTML5, but with an HTML4 VF page, you'd have a line that looks like: `<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.ResourcePackageName,'img/seasonLogos/2013_summer_aloha.png')}"/>` Perhaps your CacheManifest needs to refer to it's contents a bit more explicitly along similar lines?

Comment: I dont think thats the issue here.I know as a best practice we need to refer from static resource but here its manifest related

Comment: My thought was, how does the manifest find the static resource if it's not fully referenced?

Comment: manifest="/apex/CacheManifest" .The manifest attribute is meant for that and the second page is named as CacheManifest

Comment: Gotcha! Haven't had a need to use that (yet). I'd simply noticed that it's referenced in an entirely different way.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers are very picky about the format of cache manifest files - have you confirmed that yours parses correctly when not using the page attribute, i.e. by adding it to a regular HTML element?

Here's an example from one of my dev orgs:

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyAppController"
           showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStyleSheets="false" cache="false">
    <html manifest="/apex/MyAppCache">
```

and then the cache page is as follows - note that the CACHE MANIFEST appears on the same line as the apex:page component - if I moved it down into its own line, I recall the browsers would reject that:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" contentType="text/cache-manifest" cache="false">CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:

#js
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQuery_1_7_1)}
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.Knockout_2_1_0)}
{!URLFOR($Resource.Phonegap, 'phonegap-1.2.0-android.js')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.Phonegap, 'phonegap-1.2.0-ios.js')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.SFSmartStorePlugin)}
{!URLFOR($Resource.SFHybridAppJs)}

#css
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css')}

#images
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/images/ajax-loader.png')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/images/icons-18-black.png')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/images/icons-18-white.png')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/images/icons-36-black.png')}
{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMobile_1_1_0, 'jquery.mobile-1.1.0/images/icons-36-white.png')}
/img/samples/light_green.gif
/img/samples/light_yellow.gif
/img/samples/light_red.gif

#sessionid to force reload cache everytime the app is online:{!GETSESSIONID()}
#This is done as a work around to a limitation of JS Remoting that causes remoting actions to fail on subsequent app login.
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks and Brilliant!placing the CACHE MANIFEST beside page did the trick i believe.Thanks!!!

Comment: Just tried the above format and I am getting a problem with remoting method caching session id from last session. It does happen for the very first time you load the page after login and works fine afterwards. any idea ?

Comment: @Avidev9 did you solve this problem?

Comment: @bob buzzard you didn't have to add VFRemote.js or any standard SF javascript files?

Comment: No, because I wasn't using any of those - mine was all based around JQuery Mobile.  You'll need to add the resources that you are using - my example was explaining the format.

Comment: @BobBuzzard oh ok, i was trying to figure out if the {!GETSESSIONID()} was meant to handle that. Any idea how to include those? I can start another question if that'd be easier.

Comment: That will just refresh the recorded session id each time the page is loaded - I left it there in case it was helping without me realising.